# C script does not correctly read data from text file

Tags: c, io

I am new to working with C and I am having an issue reading in data values from a text file.

Relevant information, I'm using Visual Studio Code.

The issue, I have a text file with two columns of x and y coordinate data that I need to read into my script and then perform some calculations with them.

The data set is 21 sets of numbers in a text file like this:

```
  3.000000   3.000000 
  3.369160   3.328530 
  3.817620   3.549270
```

I am using the following code to import the data. The loop on line 21 is a check, it should output the original values + .5.

```
    #include<math.h> 
    #include<stdio.h> 

    int main() 

    { 
     FILE *file1 , *file2 ; 

     int k , n ; 

     double x[21] , y[21] ;

     n = 20 ; 

     file1 = fopen("points.data","r") ; 
     file2 = fopen("newpoints.data","w") ; 

     for ( k = 0 ; k <= n ; ++k )
     fscanf(file1,"%le %le \n",&x[k],&y[k]) ;

     for ( k = 0 ; k <= n ; ++k )
     fprintf(file2,"%f %f \n",x[k]+0.5,y[k]+0.5) ;
   }
```

The issue I think I'm having is related to reading in the values from the original text file. When I try to print the values of one of the columns to the terminal the results are erroneous values. For example, 4.450441e-308 which should be 3.00000. The output values in the file "newpoints.data" are all 0.500000.

I'm not sure what I've done wrong here, this code was provided to me as part of a homework assignment. To test things I've re-downloaded the code and the data file in a separate location from any other calculation that I've done and I'm still getting the same result.

What's going on and how do I fix it?

Comment: It seems to work correctly on my pc. The problem might be the environment.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. By environment, do you mean the workspace I'm using? It makes sense to me that I could have done something nonobvious previously that is causing problems now, I'm just not sure how to reset and fix things.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not very good at setting up environment either... Can you print x[k] and y[k] values before and after scanning? It is to check if file reading is problem.

Comment: Before reading the data x[k] and y[k] should be empty arrays of size 21. I have printed out x[k] using the follow line of code:

        for ( k = 0 ; k <= n ; ++k )
         printf("x read %le", x[k]);

Comment: Before reading the data x[k] and y[k] should be empty arrays of size 21. I have printed out x[k] using the follow line of code:

        for ( k = 0 ; k <= n ; ++k )
         printf("x read %le \n", x[k]);

I get the following in the terminal

x read 6.054889e-317 
x read 6.951928e-310 
x read 6.054889e-317 
x read 6.951937e-310 
x read 0.000000e+000 
x read 7.905050e-323
x read 2.074949e-317
x read 3.952525e-323
x read 0.000000e+000
x read 0.000000e+000
x read 6.057269e-317
x read 6.951928e-310
Additional values left off due to space restriction, but are similar in nature.

Comment: Are they same values as in points.data file?

Comment: No, they do not seem to be linked to the values in "points.data". 

I've ran the code that prints the values 3 times just now to check and I get slightly different values each time. 

For example: 
1st Run
5.051137e-317
2nd Run
9.066144e-318

Comment: As I said, try printing x[k], y[k] values before and after reading to see if it changes. Also check and compare the return value of fscanf with EOF, ELISEQ to see if fscanf failed. You might want to open points.data file and test different encodings, too.

Comment: I've printed x[k] before and after reading the file and the output values are the same. I'm not sure how to use EOF or ELISEQ, I'm searching for how to use them and I'll post another comment if I can get it working. As of right now I believe something is wrong with fscanf so I'll try to investigate that further.

Comment: Open the points.data with VSCode and look at lower right. Between spaces and CR/LF(or something look like that) is encoding. What does it say? If it isn't UTF-8(not with bom), then click it, select Save with encoding and choose UTF-8 then see if the program works ok. Note that UTF-8 with BOM is wrong one.

Comment: Okay, it says UTF-8, I'm going to try to save with encoding anyway to see what happens.